# Solving $\log(x-2) + \log(9-x) \lt 1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms

[The solution.](http://slader.com/textbook/9781305071759-precalculus-mathematics-for-calculus-7th-edition/369/exercises/79/)

Now, in comment section, a person has mentioned (and it's given in the answer behind the book) that another solution could be $2 \lt x \lt 4$. I've tried numerous times, but have not been able to get how to find this another solution. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe write down your attempt first?

Comment: @CheeHan :D That's kindda unnecessary, because I did the same question, in the exact same manner, thrice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$\log_a(x-2) + \log_a(9-x)=\log_a((x-2)(9-x)) \lt 1$$

$$(x-2)(9-x)<a$$

> EDIT: Note that we also need to have $2<x<9$ for both logarithms to
>   be well defined – b00n heT

Comment: Wouldn't it be $\lt 10$ and not $\lt e$?

Comment: I assumed that $\log(x)$ was the natural logarithm.

Comment: Note that we also need to have $2<x<9$ for both logarithms to be well defined

Comment: No, it wasn't. The base is 10.

Comment: Edited my answer choose $a=10$ :)